# Jquery how to select option with value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a variable defined in my code as follows:

```
var select = $('.selMake');
```

and I want to select the option that has the value "placeholder". How do I select the option using the variable? I need to change the html of the option that has the value "placeholder"

Comment: Could you be specific about the type of element that you want to select? Whether it is an input element ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$("select.selMake").val("placeholder");
```

Using the variable:

```
var $select = $('.selMake'); 
$select.val("placeholder");
```

It's usually good practice to use the $ prefix when indicating a jquery object.

Edit based on comment: 
Try

```
$select.find('option[value="placeholder"]').text("newText");
```

Comment: This didnt work as I was trying to do $select.val("placeholder").html("Something else"); I need to change the html of the option that has the value "placeholder"

Comment: The edit worked but you forgot to put opening quote for parameters inside find(). So the correct answer would be $select.find('option[value="placeholder"]').text("newText");

Comment: Sorry for this! I modified the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "select" and "options"? is it dropdown select HTML?

If so, you can try using code below to select the option that have value of placeholder:

```
var select = $('.selMake');

//select the option that have value of placeholder
var optionWithPlaceholder = select.find("option[value='placeholder']");

//you can do anyting here
optionWithPlaceholder.html("after edit");
```

I tried that code here: http://jsfiddle.net/Lg67qcj1/